# making a upload.php script for phonegap app

Tags: javascript, cordova, file-upload, image-uploading, ionic-framework

I'm adding a image upload feature to my phonegap / ionic app. 
So far I have the javascript code part up and running but now I need to pass the image to the server side with a php upload script.
I was hoping someone could help me with creating a php upload script that works with my code below, I'm not familiar with php.

My current phonegap javascript code that wants to pass the photo to a upload.php script.

```
</script>        
    function selectPhoto() {

        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
        function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
        { quality: 50, 
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, }
        );

    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";

        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://some.server.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
    }

    function win(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }
</script>
```

Optional: It would be nice if the script also can check if there are images in the server folder older than 60 days, if so it can delete them.

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: The last part of deleting images should be done with a cronjob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

upload.php

```
<?php
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], '/path/to/file');
```

Reference: http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/07/12/upload-image-using-file-transfer-cordova-plugin-for-ios-and-android/